# DC step-up regulator wiring

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, voltage-measurement

I'm using a pololu step-up voltage regulator (http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/2117) to go from an unregulated battery (VIN line from an Arduino, powered by a 3.7v LiPo cell) to 12V.

No matter what I do, I can't get a voltage to show across the VOUT. There's definitely a voltage applied to VIN, and it's within spec (above the 2.5V minimum for the regulator). The VOUT line just falls rapidly to 0 when I put a meter on it.

Seems like a simple enough circuit. What could I be doing wrong?

*EDIT*: The circuit below is for the final application. I tried simply supplying 5V on the VIN line to the regulator, and measuring voltage between VOUT and GND, with the same 0 value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2DpG6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's another way I tried to wire it, with the same effect

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsukrh.png)</sup>

Comment: It would be helpful if you attached a picture of your wiring setup or a schematic of your system.

Also, you could just have a bum IC!

Comment: added schematic... possible that it's a bum circuit, but i've tested two, with the same effect. so - not super likely...

Comment: If the attached schematic is not actually what you used to test, then it's the wrong schematic. Simpler is better.

Comment: Except that it is. I tested both that one and a direct wiring one, taking power from a 5V regulated wall-wart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current out of that 754410 is probably not enough to drive the boost converter. I would build the same circuit like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSjrFa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And 100 uF may not be enough. You may need 1000 uF! If so, you also want to add a few Ohms of resistance between boost-out and capacitor-plus, to avoid putting too much capacitive load on the boost converter all at once.

Comment: I'll test this out, thanks. It still doesn't answer the second part - why it won't do anything even without any load... thoughts there?

Comment: If putting 5V into the regulator gives you 0V out, then the regulator is either broken, or you're using it wrong (forgetting to enable some remote enable pin or whatever.)

Answer (score 3):

Some observations:

1. The minimum voltage for the SN754410 (according to a TI datasheet) is 4.5V. You're using the driver outside its normal range if you're feeding it from a 3.7V LiPo.
2. (Gross simplification) Best-case output current for the 754410 is 1A. Assuming perfect 3.7V, 1A output from the driver (which it won't be), that's a theoretical maximum of 3.7W. Assuming your little booster is 80% efficient (which it won't be) that's 2.96W available for your load, or around 246mA for the solenoid. Again, this is assuming lots of ideals - reality will be worse. You didn't specify the DC resistance of the solenoid control winding so I cannot predict how much current it will draw. (\Gross simplification)
3. The regulator should have \$ 33 \mu F \$ of capacitance on its input per the web link you cited. It's not shown on your drawing.
4. You haven't mentioned the A-h capacity of your 3.7V LiPo. The Arduino will be eating some of that energy too. A heavy load will likely discharge it fairly quickly - if the boost continues to receive input, it will try and draw more and more current to keep the output regulated (a switching converter shows a negative impedance load to the source.)

Comment: Thanks for #1 - I definitely missed that, and that explains why the driver wasn't putting out anything. Easy fix, I'll just take the 5V rail from the Arduino. The solenoid draws 300mA @ 12V, so ~4W (measured).

Answer (score 2):

Power out **is always less than** power in. Stepping voltage up means you draw a much bigger current at input (in the same ratio).

A Solenoid (even a small one) takes a lot of current. The output from the half H drive is unlikely to be 3V3.  To get 1.4A max current out you'll need to put in at least 5 times that. At 3V that's a whopping 7A, I think that rather exceeds the current ratings of the bridge, supply and the regulator.

With any luck your regulator has just shut down until you treat it with more respect.

Comment: the solenoid draws 300mA @ 12V. I expect the ratio to hold, drawing 4x the 3.7V coming off the VIN, so right around 1.2A... Also - I've tried this without the solenoid connected, just supplying VIN + GND to the VIN and GND pins on the regulator, to see what comes out the other side. Still 0.